# GraphicsMagick FFI issue

Tags: rust, ffi

As an exercise, I'm attempting to write a GraphicsMagick FFI wrapper in Rust. I'm having an issue replicating some reference C code:

[Demo C code](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/api.html):

```
Image
  *image = (Image *) NULL;
ImageInfo
  *imageInfo;
ExceptionInfo
  exception;

InitializeMagick(NULL);
imageInfo=CloneImageInfo(0);
GetExceptionInfo(&exception);
```

And here is my (naive) translation to Rust:

```
let img: *mut ffi::Image;
let img_info: *mut ffi::ImageInfo;
let exception: *mut ffi::ExceptionInfo = ptr::null_mut();
unsafe {             
  ffi::InitializeMagick(ptr::null_mut());
  img_info = 
    ffi::CloneImageInfo(ptr::null_mut() as *const ffi::ImageInfo);
  ffi::GetExceptionInfo(exception);
  // ...
}
```

This compiles just fine, but when I try to run it, I see:

```
magick/error.c:388: GetExceptionInfo: Assertion `exception != (ExceptionInfo *) ((void *)0)' failed
```

which is caused by `ffi::GetExceptionInfo(exception)`. The only difference seems to be that the C exception isn't "initialized", but I don't know enough about C to know if there is a difference between a null and an empty/uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between your C and Rust code is that the C version *allocates* an `ExceptionInfo` instance on the stack and passes into the `GetExceptionInfo` a pointer referencing that instance.

Your Rust code, on the other hand, passes a `NULL` pointer.

`GetExceptionInfo` specifically guards against being passed a `NULL` pointer, you can see the assertion's code [here, in magick/error.c](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/graphicsmagick/code/file/1c911b6deafd/magick/error.c#l395).

I don't know what kind of FFI bindings you use, but if the `ExceptionInfo` is fully defined in them then you should be able to allocate it on the stack and pass a reference to it just like in the C version:

```
let mut exception: ffi::ExceptionInfo = unsafe {std::mem::uninitialized()};
unsafe {ffi::GetExceptionInfo (&mut exception);}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was able to use this verbatim. I wasn't aware of `std::mem::uninitialized()`, but it was what I was missing. Thanks also for linking the relevant source code--

Answer (score 4):

The error message states (rewritten a bit):

> Assertion `exception != NULL` failed

That is, you *cannot* pass NULL to that method. Note the C code:

```
ExceptionInfo exception;
```

This is **not** a pointer. You need to allocate space for it and then pass in a reference to the allocated space.

The [documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/types.html#exceptioninfo) shows the definition:

```
typedef struct _ExceptionInfo
{
  char
    *reason,
    *description;

  ExceptionType
    severity;

  unsigned long
    signature;
} ExceptionInfo;
```

You will need to represent this in Rust. Something like this untested code:

```
extern crate libc;

#[repr(C)]
struct ExceptionInfo {
    reason: *const libc::c_char,
    description: *const libc::c_char,
    severity: ExceptionType,
    signature: libc::c_ulong,
}

#[repr(C)]
enum ExceptionType {
    UndefinedException,
    WarningException = 300,
    // the rest
}
```

Then you need to allocate it and pass a reference. More untested code:

```
let img_info;
let mut exception = ffi::ExceptionInfo::new();

unsafe {             
    ffi::InitializeMagick(ptr::null_mut());
    img_info = 
        ffi::CloneImageInfo(ptr::null_mut() as *const ffi::ImageInfo);
    ffi::GetExceptionInfo(&mut exception);
    // ...
}
```

Note that Rust style is 4 space indents.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation!